# How to get the checkbox state added in itemTpl?

Tags: android, checkbox, sencha-touch-2

In sencha touch 2.0 , is there any possibility to get the value of checkbox added in itemTpl.I have the following itemTpl.How can i get its values?

```
itemTpl: '<input type="checkbox" enabled="enabled" value="open" id="status"
name="comment_status" <tpl if="active">checked="checked"</tpl> /> {groupName}',
```

**Edit:-**

Here's the code which i tried to get the state and id of individual checkboxes,but i am unable to get them.Please help me to provide some code snippet or modify my code in correct way to get state and id.

```
var elements = Ext.DomQuery.select('#status');
Ext.each(elements, function(el){
            var item = Ext.get(el); 
            item.on('tap', function(){
                console.log('tapped:-'+item.getId());
            });
       });
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Ext.DomQuery`, see this:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery

Comment: hey buddy i tried my best to get the status and id of checked checkbox but didn't get any fruitful result.Can you provide me some code snippet for this?